# How to add an activity to a fragment? [Android Studio]

Tags: android, android-studio

I've created an app with a bottom navigation menu. That works fine, but when I try to add a new activity to one of the fragments (specifically an activity to add a new task to the tasks section fragment), the code seems to work fine but when I run the program and click the button to add new tasks it stops the whole app.

[image: button]
[image: error]

This is the code for my Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    HomeFragment fragment1 = new HomeFragment();
    FragmentManager homemanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    homemanager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1).commit();


    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
            new HomeFragment()).commit();
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_calendar:
                        selectedFragment = new CalendarFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_school:
                        selectedFragment = new SchoolFragment();
                        break;
                }

                FragmentManager navmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                navmanager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        selectedFragment).commit();

                return true;
            }
        };
```

}

This is my code for the home fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

Button addNewBtn;

public HomeFragment(){
    // Required  Empty   constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    addNewBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.btnAddNew);
    addNewBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),NewTaskHome.class));
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

}
}

I am new to Android Studio and would really welcome the help.

I don't understand why I am receiving this error?

EDIT:

[LogCat errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qOBz.png)

I've included the logCat errors when I press the "+" button.

I hope this adds more clarity.

Comment: Sorry that I can't add the images directly.. my reputation isn't high enough yet.

Comment: are you declare NewTaskHome Activity in Manifest? or you should attach crash log to your question

Comment: I couldn't understand your exact problem, was it the problem with **moving between fragment or adding Widgit in activity** ? Please add the error in **Logcat** @BrendanWilliams

Comment: Please provide the error from your Logcat @BrendanWilliams.

Comment: Is `NewTaskHome` added in the Manifest?

Comment: Ah i see.. I've added NewTaskHome into my manifest and it fixed the problem. Thank you all for your help.